# With webpack, can I put Node.js and browser code in the same file, but prevent the Node.js code making it to the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I have a file that I want to have both Node.js and browser code.

Node.js code should not be visible in the browser.

Can webpack exclude code from a file depending on the environment?

Kind of like C preprocessing directives. `#if #else, etc`.

I know that Webpack parses the code quite intensively which makes me think it can.

**Constraints**

- The Node.js code cannot make it to the browser because it might contain sensitive config options.
- I want the browser and Node code to be in the same file. I know that I could use the `webpack.IgnorePlugin` to ignore requires on a file basis, or put the shared code in the browser file and require that from the server (which I am doing now), but I want to know if its possible to have the code side by side in the same file.

---

EDIT: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
export class FooPlugin {

  $name = 'foo-plugin'

  register(app) {

    const app = koa()
    app.get('/foo', () => { this.send('foo') })
    app.set('SECRET STUFF!')
    app.start()
    this.shared()

  }

  shared(app) {

      // browser things - isomorphic react router routes, etc.

  }

  registerBrowser(app) {

      this.shared()

  }

}

// This is called in another file depending on the environment.

if (!isBrowser) {
  (new FooPlugin).register(app)
} else {
  (new FooPlugin).registerBrowser(app)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Define Plugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) to set the `NODE_ENV` and gate your code that way:

```
var define  = new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}})
```

The `DefinePlugin` will replace instances of `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your code with the supplied string, so you will end up with something like `if ('production' !== 'production')` in the compiled code. When you do a production build, Webpack runs `uglify` with dead-code-elimination which will strip out these unreachable blocks. (See [webpack howto: feature flags](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#6-feature-flags))

This is how React (and many other libraries) strip out development code before going to production.

Comment: How can I guarantee the code will be stripped? What if I have a class with two methods, one for browser things, one for node things. Is webpacks analyzer able to see if a call to a method is conditional on process.env.NODE_ENV?

Comment: I think this will make my code too messy because I'd have to wrap requires as well as the method calls. I'll update my Q with an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It seems like you could pretty easily and sensibly re-organize your code to make gating easier (for example, why not just call `register` and let the plugin handle which methods to run rather than exposing a more complicated interface?) but I understand it may not be feasible depending on the size of your project.